# Clamping floating numbers in Python?

Tags: python, math, clamp

Is there a built-in function for this in Python 2.6?

Something like:

```
clamp(myValue, min, max)
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

There's no such function, but

```
max(min(my_value, max_value), min_value)
```

will do the trick.

Comment: I always like to order it like, min(max(low, value), high).
And think of it like low < value < high. Then it also reads like a "min-max" function minmax(low, value, high)

Answer (score 63):

Numpy's [`clip`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html) function will do this.

```
>>> import numpy
>>> numpy.clip(10,0,3)
3
>>> numpy.clip(-4,0,3)
0
>>> numpy.clip(2,0,3)
2
```

Comment: This seems to be extremely slow, though. I'm guessing it's because this function was meant for arrays.

Comment: @Micael: Numpy is always meant for arrays, where it works faster for than any pure-Python alternative. If a person is worrying about the speed of pure-Python it's usually an indication they need to redesign to use arrays, offload, or switch languages.

Answer (score 11):

I think the question is answered but here's an alternative DIY solution if anyone needs it:

```
def clip(value, lower, upper):
    return lower if value < lower else upper if value > upper else value
```

(Slightly faster than @Sven Marnach's answer - even when in bounds).