# Write Numeric Manipulation in Python in 1 line

Tags: python

i have a simple problem in Python where i need to return a value that is equal to floor if it is smaller than floor, and return ceiling if the value is larger than ceiling. I'm not sure if there is a simpler way to do so. What i will do is:

```
def floor_ceil(x):
    floor = 0
    ceil = 100
    if x < floor:
       return floor
    elif x > ceil:
       return ceil
    return x
```

Are there simpler ways to do so? The code looks clunky

Comment: "if it is smaller than floor," ... "if the value is larger than ceiling": I don't think that is ever the case, by definition.

Comment: But from your function, you'd want a clip- or clamp-style function. What you have is currently fine.

Comment: You could consider `def floor_ceil(x, floor=0, ceil=100):` as to make your function more generic.

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775731/clamping-floating-numbers-in-python

Comment: Also worth mentioning [`numpy.clip`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could reuse the built-in `max` and `min`:

```
def floor_ceil(x):
    return max(0, min(100, x))
```